# TinyMCE unable to upload images in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, file-upload, tinymce, internet-explorer-11

I've implemented TinyMCE 4 with drag and drop image upload which works well in Firefox and Chrome. However when attempting to upload an image in IE11, it gives the error

> SCRIPT87: Invalid Argument.

My setup is simple as follows:

```
tinymceOptions = {
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: ["paste"],
        paste_data_images: true
}
tinymce.init(tinymceOptions);
```

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/s00fka6u/6/

Is this a known issue, or perhaps something with my local environment? Is there a workaround for this? I'm on IE version 11.0.10240.16766 on Windows 10

Comment: On doing some initial debugging it appears the error is occuring on line 551 of /tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.js:

    items[contentType] = dataTransfer.getData(contentType);

Comment: I have the same issue with Disqus and Microsoft webpages with IE11 on Windows 10! Once I want to upload a file, the file type is missing and so the webpage will give an error. Can't find anything on the web for this error...

Comment: It's bizarre that it's not more widely discussed. I've logged an issue for this on the tinymce github page now (details in post). Sounds like it's IE's fault (no surprise there - 15 years on, same old story.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation it turned out this was a recreatable issue/bug with IE11 and not a local configuration or setup issue.

I have logged a bug at the tinymce github issues page here if anyone wants to follow the progress:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/2918